# Is it possible to make it so that all users can use the same XP Mode in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtualization

I have installed XP Mode within Windows 7, and installed all the necessary programs that will only run in XP. The problem I have is when another user logs on to the same PC and clicks on XP Mode, rather than loading the same XP where all programs were installed it creates a new virtual machine.

Is it possible to make it so that all users can use the same XP Mode in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem is that the virtual machine (XP mode) is created under the first user account profile so this will not be able to be used by other users. My guess is that the solution is not trivial. I reviewed the following link and it's not clear whether the users there had any real success. At least there is nothing there that doesn't look contorted in some way.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7036a4da-5764-4a95-a52a-a2e93f39e27a/windows-xp-mode-1-vm-for-multiple-users?forum=w7itprovirt

You might be better off trying a different virtualization tool, (provided you have XP licenses), such as Oracle Virtual Box or VMware Workstation. These tools give you better control over where virtual machine files are saved (you can save in a public location), but the caveat is each user will need to know how to use those tools.

I don't use Virtual Box often (I use WMware a lot, and used to use MS Virtual PC and Virtual Server a lot), but I believe it works directly with *.vhd files so you might be able to use your Windows XP mode vhd that way.

http://www.sysprobs.com/how-to-open-run-microsoft-vhd-files-on-virtualbox-pre-installed-vhd-images

Sorry about the links, but there is a lot of information (including screen shots) in there. I'm trying to point you in a direction that gives you some options.